# How do I open Vim using Command?

Tags: vim

I just downloaded and started using Vim so I'm still a bit confused with it. I've been watching tutorial videos and I see that I can open Vim by typing vim in command. However when I do it I get

> 'vim' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Did I need to install something else? Also I want to code and compile C in vim, would I need to install a compiler?

Comment: Is the executable in your $PATH? Also yes, you'd need to install a compiler, vim doesn't compile code for you.

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to use gvim (the gui vim editor)? If you are, then you can use `gvim` to start it or just click on the `.exe` file. Otherwise you can try the `vi` command to start it.

Comment: What environment are you on by the way? Windows, Mac OS X, Linux?

Comment: I'm using Windows. Sorry I'm really new at this.

Comment: I voted to close, sorry, because it has nothing to do with vim editing, even if the problem is about vim.  in general, it is a kind of using application under windows question. you can `s/vim/any/`

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke Vim (or `gvim`, the GUI application) with the full path, e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\vim.exe"
```

The Vim installer doesn't add the location to the PATH. In Windows, you can create a *shortcut* (`*.lnk`) in your Start Menu, or re-run `"C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\install.exe"`, which has an option to *install batch files to C:\Windows*, or manually add `"C:\Program Files\vim\vim74"` to your PATH via the Control Panel.

---

Vim is just a (very advanced and powerful) text editor, so it ships with syntax highlighting for most programming languages, but unlike *IDEs*, it doesn't come with the full toolset of compiler, linker, debugger, etc. You need to separately install that (e.g. *mingw*, or Microsoft's compiler from the Windows SDK, or any other).

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\>vim somefile.txt
```

During Vim (for Win32) install, you have the option to install batch files for launching vim from the command-line.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. And is it too late to install that?

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you install vim properly. (https://www.vim.org/download.php)
2. On Windows. Don't forget to set the *environment variables* (simply add \vim\vim**; at the end of the classpath)
3. Type vim at command line (gvim.exe will start the Graphic user interface software).

If you want to compile and run c program using the command line, you should download the GCC Compiler and follow the same procedure as mentioned before (The classpath thing). Then you can compile C program using gcc command.